# How to resolve Pypi dependency when building conda package

Tags: python, build, conda

I am trying to create a conda package from my project. But I can't find out how to satisfy pypi requirement when building the conda package.

**meta.yaml:**

```
package:
  name: speedstrom
  version: "0.0.1"

source:
    path: .

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools
    - cycler
    - llvmlite
    - matplotlib
    - numba
    - numpy
    - pandas
    - pyparsing
    - python-dateutil
    - pytz
    - scikit-learn
    - scipy
    - simplejson
    - six
  run:
    - python
    - cycler
    - llvmlite
    - matplotlib
    - numba
    - numpy
    - pandas
    - pyparsing
    - python-dateutil
    - pytz
    - scikit-learn
    - scipy
    - simplejson
    - six

test:
  imports:
    - speedstrom

about:
  license: WTFPL
```

**setup.py:**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

import speedstrom

setup(
    name='speedstrom',
    version=speedstrom.__version__,
    packages=find_packages(),
    author="Luc",
    description="Nyström On-Line implementation",
    long_description=open('README.rst').read(),
    install_requires=[
        "cycler==0.10.0",
        "llvmlite==0.18.0",
        "matplotlib==2.0.2",
        "nab==1.0",
        "numba==0.33.0",
        "numpy==1.12.1",
        "pandas==0.20.2",
        "pyparsing==2.1.4",
        "python-dateutil==2.6.0",
        "pytz==2017.2",
        "scikit-learn==0.18.1",
        "scipy==0.19.0",
        "simplejson==3.11.1",
        "six==1.10.0"],
    include_package_data=True,
    license="WTFPL",
)
```

The package `simplejson` is only available in the Pypi and not in the conda index. When I run `conda build`, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Setuptools downloading is disabled in conda build. Be sure to add all dependencies in the meta.yaml  url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/simplejson/r
```

which is related to this pypi dependancy.

I then tried to upload the package `simplejson` to the conda index but I failed and I was wondering if there wasn't a way to enable setuptools downloading with conda?

Comment: AFAIK, there is not. You have to use conda packages as dependencies. Do you need 3.11.1 of simplejson? 3.10.0 is available already.